# Scala Event Sourcing with Kafka

Tags: scala, architecture, apache-kafka, event-sourcing, akka-persistence

For a microservice I need the functionality to persist state (changes). Essentially, the following happens:

```
case class Item(i: Int)
val item1 = Item(0)
val item2 = exec(item1)
```

Where `exec` is user defined and hence not known in advance. As an example, let's assume this implementation:

```
def exec(item: Item) = item.copy(i = item.i + 1)
```

After each call to `exec`, I want log the state changes (here: `item.i: 0->1`) so that...

1. there is a **history** (e.g. list of tuples like `(timestamp, what has changed, old value, new value)`)
2. state changes and snapshots could be persisted efficiently to a **local file systems** and sent to a **journal**
3. Arbitrary consumers (not only the specific producer where the changes originated) could be **restored** from the journal/snapshots
4. As less **dependencies** to libraries and infrastructure as possible (it is a small project, complex infrastructure/server installations & maintenance is not possible)

I know that the EventStore DB is probably the best solution, however, in the given environment (a huge enterprise with a lot of policies), it is not possible for me to install & run it. The only infrastructural options are a RDBMS or Kafka. I'd like to go with Kafka as it seems to be the natural fit in this event sourcing use case.

I also noticed that Akka Persistence seems to handle all of the requirements well. But I have a couple of questions:

- Are there any alternatives I missed?
- Akka Persistence's Kafka integration is only available through a community plugin that is not maintained regularly. Seems to me, as this is not a common use case. Is there any reason the outlined architecture is not wide spread?
- Is cloning possible? In the Akka documentation it says:

> "So, if two different entities share the same persistenceId,
>   message-replaying behavior is corrupted."

So, let's assume two application instances, `one` and `two`, both have unique `persistenceId`s. Could `two` be restored (cloned) from `one`'s journal? Even if they don't share the same Id (which is not allowed)?

- Are there any complete examples of this architecture available?